# Identify the min and max x-y coordinates of an ee.Geometry (Earth Engine)

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, coordinates

I am using the EE API in a Python Jupyter Notebook.

I am building a map based on the LSIB_SIMPLE country boundaries.
My objective is to display my information in a map and adapt the zoom to fit the country size (Singapore is way smaller than Congo for example)

I would like to compute both the longest north-south and east-west lines inside the country to adapt my zoom accordingly on this object:

```py
country_code = CG
country = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017').filter(ee.Filter.eq('country_co', country_code))

geom = country.geometry()
```

- Is there a way to find the 4 needed points in the geometry object (northest, southest, eastest, westest) so that I can compute distances between them ?

Comment: what does the notebook show after you type `geom.` and then hit the tab key?

Comment: nothing actually

Comment: how about `dir(geom)`

Comment: too many thing to go in a comment...
I checked `.coordinates` that is an invocation but with the `.getInfo()["coordinates"]` I retreived the array of coordinates.

Comment: you could throw those into a `shapely` geometry and get the area and extent

Comment: It was just to show that I wasn't asking something out of the blue. And in the end I was on good track as the second question was the path I followed for my answer. Anyway I'll update it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to [@Paul H](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/12552/paul-h) for the idea.

I ended up finding a solution that compute the 4 cardinal points of my AOI and adapt the zoom to the longest diagonal :

```py
from haversine import haversine

def update_zoom(asset_id):
    """search for the dimension of the AOI and adapt the map zoom acordingly
    
    Args: 
        asset_id (str): the assetID
    
    Returns: 
        zoom (int): the zoom value riquired
    """
    
    #retreive the asset 
    geom = ee.FeatureCollection(asset_id).geometry()
    coordinates = geom.getInfo()["coordinates"]
    #transform into a single list of all the coordinates
    shape = []
    get_coords(coordinates, shape)
    #in the coordinates search for the 4 cardinal points of the aoi
    #gee format coords [lng, lat]
    count = 0 
    for coords in shape: #perimeter of each shape
        count += 1
        if count == 1:
            north = coords
            east = coords
            south = coords
            west = coords
            continue
            
        if coords[0] < west[0]:
            west = coords
        if coords[0] > east[0]:
            east = coords
        if coords[1] < south[1]:
            south = coords
        if coords[1] > north[1]:
            north = coords

    maxsize = max(haversine(east, west), haversine(north, south))
    
    lg = 40075 #number of displayed km at zoom 1
    zoom = 1
    while lg > maxsize:
        zoom += 1
        lg /= 2
        
    return zoom-1

def get_coords(coordinates, array_coord=[]):
    """get all the coordinates and set them in a single table of tuple without knowing in advance the depth of the tab"""
    if isinstance(coordinates[0], float):
        array_coord.append((coordinates[0], coordinates[1]))
        return array_coord
    
    for item in coordinates:
        get_coords(item,array_coord)
```

feel free to suggest modifications there is always room for improvement

Comment: or just look it up ~ https://gist.github.com/graydon/11198540

Comment: good to know that it exist. The advantage of my code is that it's geometry agnostic so I can now use it for any asset I can provide.

Answer (score 1):

You can find min/max coordinates easily with server-side Earth Engine. Call `.bounds()` on the geometry or feature, get the `.coordinates()`, then reduce the lats and lons by min and max.

```py
geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-121.04086404798966, 36.97562343255799],
          [-121.38144021986466, 36.93611720712966],
          [-121.06283670423966, 36.544342687193584],
          [-120.47506814955216, 36.38088239731507],
          [-120.10153299330216, 36.50902912598594],
          [-120.46957498548966, 36.486949964934816],
          [-120.52999979017716, 36.96245696791018],
          [-119.93124490736466, 37.14658010572364],
          [-120.62887674330216, 37.51348410687124],
          [-121.16171365736466, 37.16409233412239]]]);

bounds = ee.Array(ee.List(geometry.bounds().coordinates()).get(0))

min_coords = bounds.reduce(ee.Reducer.min(), [0]).project([1]).toList()
max_coords = bounds.reduce(ee.Reducer.max(), [0]).project([1]).toList()

x_min = min_coords.get(0)
y_min = min_coords.get(1)
x_max = max_coords.get(0)
y_max = max_coords.get(1)

from pprint import pprint
pprint(bounds.getInfo())
print()
print('x_min:', x_min.getInfo())
print('y_min:', y_min.getInfo())
print('x_max:', x_max.getInfo())
print('y_max:', y_max.getInfo())
```

Answer (score 0):

With Python the script can be as succinct as below:

```
def MinMaxXY(geometry):
    x_min = ee.List(ee.List(geometry.coordinates().get(0)).map(lambda x: ee.List(x).get(0))).reduce(reducer=ee.Reducer.min()).getInfo()
    x_max = ee.List(ee.List(geometry.coordinates().get(0)).map(lambda x: ee.List(x).get(0))).reduce(reducer=ee.Reducer.max()).getInfo()
    y_min = ee.List(ee.List(geometry.coordinates().get(0)).map(lambda x: ee.List(x).get(1))).reduce(reducer=ee.Reducer.min()).getInfo()
    y_max = ee.List(ee.List(geometry.coordinates().get(0)).map(lambda x: ee.List(x).get(1))).reduce(reducer=ee.Reducer.max()).getInfo()
    return x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max
```

And a simple test:

```
geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-121.04086404798966, 36.97562343255799],
          [-121.38144021986466, 36.93611720712966],
          [-121.06283670423966, 36.544342687193584],
          [-120.47506814955216, 36.38088239731507],
          [-120.10153299330216, 36.50902912598594],
          [-120.46957498548966, 36.486949964934816],
          [-120.52999979017716, 36.96245696791018],
          [-119.93124490736466, 37.14658010572364],
          [-120.62887674330216, 37.51348410687124],
          [-121.16171365736466, 37.16409233412239]]])

MinMaxXY(geometry)

(-121.38144021986466,
 -119.93124490736466,
 36.38088239731507,
 37.51348410687124)
```